# Why we only have access to Protected and Public methods in aspx or ascx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms

I have an ASP.net webform project, when I have a `protected` or `public` method I can call them from my inline codes in aspx but I can't call `private` methods. Why? It behaves like **[inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173149%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** classes. Is it related to inheritance?

My ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ViewFamilyTree.aspx.cs" Inherits="Mobini.WebForms.ViewFamilyTree" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <%= GetHelloWorlds_Protected() %> <%-- Works --%>
        <%= GetHelloWorlds_Public() %> <%-- Works --%>
        <%= GetHelloWorlds_Private() %> <%-- Error: is inaccessible due to its protection level --%>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
namespace Mobini.WebForms
{
    public partial class ViewFamilyTree : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private string GetHelloWorlds_Private()
        {
            return "Hello Worlds";
        }

        protected string GetHelloWorlds_Protected()
        {
            return "Hello Worlds";
        }

        public string GetHelloWorlds_Public()
        {
            return "Hello Worlds";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Private methods and properties can be called ONLY from the same class. ASPX file certainly doesn't meet that criteria, does it?

Comment: Umm because they are private?

Comment: "Is it related to inheritance?" -- Notice the `Inherits="Mobini.WebForms.ViewFamilyTree` in your ASPX file.

Comment: Yes @walther , But is an aspx file a class?

Comment: @TyCobb I see that, But is an aspx file a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why we only have access to Protected and Public methods in aspx or
>   ascx?

Simple answer to your question is: Yes it is because of inheritance. Since in aspx file, there is a directive which specifies the class to inherit, *(which usually is a code behind class)*

This brings to your second question:

> But is an aspx file a class?

Yes. At compilation, a class will be generated for `aspx` file. In original implementation of ASP.Net 2.0, `aspx` class and code behind class were same partial classes like [winform](/questions/tagged/winform). But Later it was changed due to *flexibility*.

> See: [Codebehind and Compilation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163675.aspx)
>
> At this point, you may be wondering why the ASP.NET team bothered to
>   use inheritance at all with this new codebehind model. ASP.NET could
>   easily generate all of the control variable declarations in addition
>   to the rendering methods from the .aspx file as a partial class which
>   could then be merged with your simplified codebehind class. This is
>   exactly how Windows Forms works in the .NET Framework 2.0. All of the
>   designer-generated code is placed into a sibling partial class which
>   is then merged with your application logic and event handlers into a
>   single Form-derived class, creating a clean separation between
>   machine-generated code and developer code without resorting to
>   inheritance.
>
> Well, it turns out that the **original implementation of codebehind in
>   ASP.NET 2.0 did exactly this—the codebehind class was just a partial
>   class that was merged with the parsed .aspx file class definition. It
>   was simple and effective, but unfortunately, not flexible enough. The
>   problem with this model was that it was no longer possible to deploy
>   the codebehind files in precompiled binary assemblies along with
>   intact .aspx files since they now had to be compiled** at the same
>   time (a restriction when using partial classes is that all partial
>   pieces of a class must be merged during a single compilation, and
>   class definitions cannot span assemblies). This restriction was
>   unacceptable to many developers as they were already used to being
>   able to deploy binary codebehind assemblies along with intact .aspx
>   files which could then be updated in place without having to
>   recompile. This is, in fact, the exact model used by default in Visual
>   Studio .NET 2003, and is thus very prevalent in practice.
>
> As a result of reintroducing the inheritance model and shifting the
>   partial class into the base class, .aspx files can now be deployed and
>   compiled independently from the codebehind class. To complete the
>   picture, you need some way to generate the sibling partial classes
>   containing control variable declarations during compilation or
>   deployment since this was always done in the past on demand in
>   response to requests. Enter the ASP.NET compiler.

Answer (score 2):

> It behaves like inheritance classes.

It behaves that way because it IS inheritance. What the ASP.NET compiler does is inherit your "code-behind-file" from the view file you created.

For your example you have `CodeBehind="ViewFamilyTree.aspx.cs" Inherits="Mobini.WebForms.ViewFamilyTree"` and so a class like the following is created:

```
public class MyView : Mobini.WebForms.ViewFamilyTree
{
    protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
         writer.WriteLine("My view content header");
         writer.WriteLine(GetHelloWorlds_Protected());
         writer.WriteLine(GetHelloWorlds_Public());
         writer.WriteLine(GetHelloWorlds_Private());
         writer.WriteLine("My view content footer");
    }
}
```

So `GetHelloWorlds_Protected()` and `GetHelloWorlds_Public()` are accessible, but `GetHelloWorlds_Private()` is not.